# Styling Buttons Alert - Ionic3

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

Could anyone please help me to style the alert box and buttons in android platform like the same in Ios? Just like the following picture?

[image]

like

[image]

I could change the color by the following css property.

```
.buttonCss { 
button.alert-button:nth-child(1){
  color: #37474f !important;
}

button.alert-button:nth-child(2){
  color:#1565c0 !important;
}
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it by using `setMode` function:

```
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create(...);
alert.setMode('ios');
```

Comment: Awesome bro, its working. But dont know why somebody downvoted this answer.